# Why ubuntu software center doesn't have the latest version of softwares?

Tags: software-center

Say I want to install Codeblocks(C/C++ IDE) using Ubuntu Software centre. But, if I do that I will install version 10, when I can have version 12 if I download package from Codeblocks website. The same happens with Eclipse. Ubuntu software centre has version 3.x and I can have 4.x from Eclipse website.

Question is why ubuntu software centre doesn't have the latest version of a software? Is this the lack of interest of developers, not to update their latest release on ubuntu software centre? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Repositories included with Ubuntu are maintained by Canonical and a few third-parties. They have to first evaluate all software and updates before they are allowed.

However that's why there are PPA Repositories that you can subscribe to. Most software developers maintain a PPA so users can get the latest updates as soon as they're available. You can usually find the PPA for a program by checking the Developer's webpage. Alternatively you can search **http://Launchpad.net** for a specific software.

Some developers don't provide a PPA however, and that's when you'll have to manually download the DEB install file each time there's an update and install from that.

Worst case, some devs only develop for Linux in general and you'll have to download a ZIP or TAR.GZ archive that contains install scripts or even just a self contained program for you to run.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Y-PPA to fetch PPA info. But, on search returns many results and I don't know which one is the correct one. For example, I want to install [code::blocks](https://launchpad.net/codeblocks) and PPA search returns [4 results](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e179/iamcreasy/codeblocks_zps05b1c70f.png). How do I know which one to pick?

Comment: Codeblocks is already available in the Ubuntu Repos. I just did: `apt-cache search codeblocks` on my PC and got back the program you're looking at. There's no need for a PPA. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Hmm. Now I deleted the added PPA and updated Software centre, CB 12 is there. But, what to do when multiple PPA shows up? Do I need to take a wild shot or should I contact the developers.

Comment: @iamcreasy You can look up the PPA on Launchpad. Just go to google and enter: "launchpad ppa:username/package", it should be the first result. Just check for how recently the packages have been updated and if their versions correspond with the Developer's website. In this case, "codeblocks" devs didn't have an official PPA and only provided the software in .tar.gz package, so all the PPAs are unofficial.

Comment: One more question, how did you know just by `apt-cache search codeblocks` that you have codeblocks version 12? I had version 10 before I added the PPA.

Comment: Okay here's something better for you. After perusing the Codeblock Wiki I found they linked to some recommended (un)official PPAs. So if you want the latest without manually installing the debs from their site just run this: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa` and then run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install codeblock`. From now on you'll be sure to have the latest.