# Why does the Ubuntu package manager install nodejs v4.2.6 by default?

Tags: apt, software-installation, nodejs

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on 64bit in a VM.

To be clear, I'm wondering why that specific version of nodejs is the one in the repo. Is it because the developer of nodejs choose to make that the default or is it due to something else?

Comment: @user535733 I think that RayB is talking about the `nodejs` package

Comment: @Yamboy1 I suspect so, too. But that's not what he said in the title, and we're not psychic. Maybe he's wondering why a 2-year-old OS has 2-year old versions in it. Perhaps we may never know....

Comment: nodejs is more commonly called node. The only place I've ever seen it being called nodejs is in the ubuntu repos

Comment: I guess I'm just biased to node.js after doing a lot of work using it

Comment: But the `nodejs` package does have v4.2.6 on the repo for 16.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/nodejs

Comment: Plus it has a [nodejs] tag

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of the "why doesn't ubuntu have latest versions of software" question, which I again can't seem to find right now.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've updated my question to make more sense. 
@dobey Thanks for suggesting that (https://askubuntu.com/questions/274275/why-ubuntu-software-center-doesnt-have-the-latest-version-of-softwares) it it's a good start. I'm not wondering why the repo doesn't have the latest software. I'm wondering if there's a specific reason it's still on that version instead any other 4.x or other major updates.

Comment: I'm not sure why

Comment: I've put some extra info about it in my answer though

Comment: Sure enough, Node.js v4.2.6 was the [most recent release](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) at the [feature freeze time](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) of Ubuntu 16.04, Feb 18th 2016.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That still doesn't explain 18.04. The most recent release at the feature freeze time of Ubuntu 17.10 should have been v8.9.1 unless I messed up my calculations

Comment: @Yamboy1: You're right that it doesn't. It only explains the version in Xenial as asked in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that the `nodejs` package seems so outdated is that it hasn't been updated since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS came out, but you can install v9 of `node.js` using these commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: Thanks this is a pretty good answer. I guess I didn't realized that Ubuntu 16 was older and that could be the cause. Reading up on this question explained a lot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: Yeah, but Ubuntu 18.04 hasn't been release yet and it only has node v6

Comment: Also @RayB if this answered your question, don't forget to click the check mark next to it

Comment: just why, nodejs. Half of the world uses it and you can't update it via apt. Can't believe it.

Comment: Note that `setup_9.x` is not the only option, and no longer the latest.  See https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#deb (and scroll down slightly) for up-to-date versions of the above commands.